# To what extent is aural language comprehension based on a post-processing model, and what are the factors involved?

Tags: speech-recognition, morphemes, spoken-language, word-boundaries

It occurred to me that what we hear and interpret as speech is often an inarticulate garble of phonemes that native speakers process with lightning speed (usually) to come up with a clear and specific meaning.

For example, in English if you are a native speaker and you hear

> Yerg'nahaftagedoudaherenow!

you probably parse it instantly and correctly as

> You're going to have to get out of here now!

But non-native speakers would be completely flummoxed unless there were sufficient contextual clues—angry face, threatening or warning gestures, tone of voice—to make most of the meaning clear.

I'm wondering how much of this post-processing is based on pattern recognition, how much is contextual or modal or extra-linguistic, and so on. Certainly if I were to bring up an abstruse topic out of the blue, and spoke in a similarly rapid and inarticulate manner, comprehension would go way down, even for native speakers.

Comment: You appear to be confusing writing with speech. What any native speaker does is instantly understand an utterance, correct; but it's not at all clear that any, let alone all, native speakers use written graphemes, or even orthodox morphemes, to structure their understandings. Many discourses are entirely a matter of fixed phrases used for pragmatic and phatic significance; the rest is likely not "processed" beyond recognition as a fixed phrase.

Comment: I'm not speaking about graphemes. They're unfortunately the only way I have to render what I hear in a written question.

Comment: Good question, but how would one quantify these things? It is a combination of all of those things...perhaps someone can give a summary of the most salient points.

Comment: Phonemes work fine, and that's what they're for. If IPA is a problem, there are lots of ASCII workarounds like /iy/ vs /i/, etc. The point, though, is that talking about pre- or post-processing at this stage of our knowledge of human language understanding is putting the processing before the horse, let alone the human.

Comment: @jlawler: I see no point in using IPA here. Details of pronunciation are not needed to illustrate what we already know. As to "post-processing": I don't know what your objection is exactly, but the way Rob used it sounds like a metaphor to me. I do agree that a technical neurological answer is probably still outside of our reach.

Comment: My point was not to precisely communicate a particular set of phonemes, but to approximate a natural, hurried form of speech. I probably could have written a placeholder like **<garbled speech with highlights>** and conveyed as much as is needed to get the idea across.

Comment: What is the 'post'-processing here? What part of 'this' comes before? Can you clarify the pieces and what ordering you're thinking of? Is this multimodal (using vision too) - or can you restrict it to just sound)? I'm worried that a good answer would be 'Yes' and then a book.

Comment: @Mitch: It seems to me—and I am not a linguist—that language is not processed word by word like data packets. I believe we hear highlights in an oral statement and put them together after the fact. Sometimes we can go the other way and be predictive about what the last part of a sentence based on what we've already heard, but mostly we fill in details after the fact to arrive at a complete comprehension. I noticed this while watching movies when the dialogue wasn't clear. Sometimes two or three phonemes would be all that was needed to make sense of a longer statement. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Robusto: I liked your garbled speech. No need to remove the fun part.

Comment: If memory serves, there are different models of natural language processing, all with their bonuses and problems: the sausage machine, bottom-up (phone-phoneme-word-POS/role-meaning), top-down, even the historically discredited behaviorist model of a complicated reaction diagram isn't out of the question. Sometimes I'll hear a garbled phrase that makes no sense, then I'll 'replay' it back in my head and all of a sudden it all falls together. There's lots of science

Comment: @Mitch: I would like to see some of that science, or an interpretation of it.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I believe psycholinguistics studies. People involved in computational speech synthesis and speech recognition probably have to concern themselves with this stuff too.

Comment: I'd like more details too (I don't have them), but as @hippietrail said, psycholinguistics is -the- field of study for this. If you wiki 'speech processing' you'll only get engineering techniques for it, not study of how humans actually do it (so it'd be a start but not exactly what you're looking for).

Comment: I can't agree with the *only* regarding speech processing. It's often not possible to make much progress in these fields without researching how humans do it. There have been occasions when various fields within linguistics haven't really had much attention before the computer guys came along. Despite terms like "software engineer", most work developing software is not much like the discipline of engineering at all.